# GeoDjango can't find geos library

Tags: django, macos, postgresql, geodjango

When attempting to fire up the django server, I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not import user-defined GEOMETRY_BACKEND "geos".
```

I'm running postgresql8.4 on Mac OS Lion.

I've used Macports to install PostGIS. Here's what $ port installed shows:

postgis @1.5.2_1+postgresql84
  postgis @1.5.2_1+postgresql90
  postgis @1.5.3_0+postgresql90
  postgis @1.5.3_0+postgresql91 (active)

Here's what I get when attempting to determine what version of PostGIS I've got:

```
geodjango=# SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-1.5": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT postgis_lib_version()"
PL/pgSQL function "postgis_full_version" line 11 at SQL statement
```

Answer (score 14):

Just in case some developers are facing this problem on Ubuntu, I solved it just installing libgeos-lib

`sudo apt-get install libgeos-dev`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with postgis via MacPorts in combination with Django, although I could execute `select postgis_full_version();` without issues. This answer helped me: http://pragmaticstartup.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/django-core-exceptions-improperlyconfigured-could-not-import-user-defined-geometry_backend-geos/

The solution for me was to add

```
export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/local/lib/
```

to `~/.profile`. (Don't forget to source it before trying again)

Answer (score 6):

I found that I'd originally installed geos through pip.

Once I downloaded the new GEOS library from:
http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks#geos

Then installed it.

Last, I added to my path (~/.bash_profile):

```
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GEOS.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib/:$PATH
```

It worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the [geos](http://trac.osgeo.org/geos/) library?

It's included in the [instructions for installing GeoDjango with macports](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#macports).

Comment: Yep. Ran the installs outlined on the GeoDjango site using macports, though it's entirely likely some of these were previous installed and therefore things were not in the proper order.